# Elasticsearch POST /delete_by_query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to delete document in Elasticsearch using POST /delete_by_query but it didn't delete the documents when executed but no error thrown. The funny thing is it works on some index but not some others. Is there any reason why this is happening?

```
POST /my-index/_delete_by_query?slices=1&requests_per_second=-1&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&refresh=true&conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=true
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "myAttributeKey1": [
                    "myAttributeValue1"
                  ],
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "myAttributeValue2",
            "fields": [
              "myAttributeKey2"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields",
            "default_operator": "and",
            "max_determinized_states": 10000,
            "enable_position_increments": true,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
            "phrase_slop": 0,
            "escape": false,
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
            "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

Comment: What response do you get from the call? What count do you see in `total` and in`deleted`?

Comment: @Val Here's the response
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 0,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 0,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}

Comment: Ok, `total: 0` means your query is not matching any document, hence why nothing gets deleted... Try to fix your query using the `_search` endpoint and once your query is ok, you can run it through the delete by query endpoint again and it will work.

Comment: @Val even using `_search` isn't working. I work on two different elasticSearch hosts, it works on the first one but not on the other. Is it because of the indexes settings?

Comment: Again, if your query doesn't return anything, you need to fix it. If you work on two different hosts, it might be that the index ont he second hosts is not set up the same way... please make sure it's the case.

Comment: @Val is there any specific setting on the index that might cause this?

Comment: How would I know? Show the settings and mappings of both of your indexes and then we can compare them

Comment: Please delete that (it's not an answer) and update your question instead. After looking at the diff of both, they are semantically equivalent, so the problem is not there

Comment: @Val so what might be the problem do you think?

Comment: Well, are you sure that both of your indexes contain the same documents with the same mappings? How many hits in the first index, vs the second index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the index mapping was the issue. Below is the index mapping. I should have used term `myAttributeKey1.keyword` instead of `myAttributeKey1` which can be solved by fix the index mapping.

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "myAttributeKey1": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here as comparison of the mapping that you might want have

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "myAttributeKey1": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```